# How to Create a CustomAuthendiactionStateProvider for a Blazor wasm Aplication created by using dotnet cli which is Authendiuacted by MSAL

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly

I'm working in a Blazor wasm application that consumes Microsost oauth Authendication (Azure ADD). it was created by dotnet cli. after Authendication has done. After I need to include few more claims (Ex:user role claim) into the AuthendicationState.So i need to create a CustomAuthendicationStateProvider. I dont't know how to resolve it.

I created customAuthendicationStateProvider Class inherted it with the default one & registered it in the program.cs. but after that application is throwing runtime error.If i remove the registered code it works fine as usuall.